# change src of script in vue2leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I use vue2leaflet for show map ,i want to change SDK of this module to

```
 <script src="https://static.neshan.org/sdk/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Which version of `vue2leaflet`? How are you loading `vue2leaflet`?

Comment: @IvanSanchez 
i use last version of vue2leaflet and i load as a component in my vuejs project